# In the code::blocks compiler for linux, how can one add compilation flags like '-lrt' or '-lboost_thread'?

Tags: linux, g++, codeblocks, boost-thread

Debugging in gdb is not convenient for me so I enjoy the nice debugging interface that code::blocks offers. Now that I have moved my project into an area where those flags are required (the ones in the title, of course), I find that I can't compile on code::blocks anymore :/.

Comment: I just had this problem trying to compile with the '-pthread' option.

Apparently '-pthread' is required for both the compile and linker stages. Putting '-pthread' in the "other link options" worked for me.

Just thought I would add this as it suggests the linker options are sent to the compiler if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi everyone I figured out how to add the -lrt. Since -lrt is passed to the linker and not the compiler you can go to Settings->Compiler and Debugger->linker options then press add and after doing a "locate lrt" I found this cute library "/usr/lib/libaticalrt.so." I added the library in the linker options and now those errors disappeared... Time to try boost!

EDIT: Boost was solved in a similar manner. The library represented by lboost_thread is libboost_thread.so. A locate found it at: "/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so." Adding it in the linker options solved the problem :D

Comment: I tried the same thing with -lglut but `locate lglut` doesn't return anything.. Nor am I finding anything in Synaptic Package Manager when searching for "lglut". Any ideas? btw the error motivating this is "undefined reference to 'glEnableClientState'

Comment: try doing 'sudo updatedb' to update locate's database. Then do the locates. You can try something like "locate glu | grep .so" to find all libraries with the word glu in it