# Using command line arguments when compile with gcc in codeblocks

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks

So my question is simple.

I want to compile a C project file in gcc compiler 4.4.8.

In windows cmd window I can type :

```
gcc -std=c99 -O2 -DCONTEST -s -static -lm name.c -o name.exe
```

In **Code::Blocks** how can I change the compiler default arguments with the above?
I wanted to build a c file and I geting errors like

```
error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode|
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In the code::blocks compiler for linux, how can one add compilation flags like '-lrt' or '-lboost\_thread'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560156/in-the-codeblocks-compiler-for-linux-how-can-one-add-compilation-flags-like)

Comment: It's not dublicate. The question you refer has nothing to do with mines! Please re-edit my question back. I found the solution myshelf

Answer (score 2):

Ok to put your preferred arguments to gnu compiler go to :

**Settings -> Debugger -> Compiler settings -> Other Options**

and paste there your arguments!

Example:

```
-std=c99 -O2 -DCONTEST -s -static -lm
```

Comment: I must wait 2 days for some reason.